# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data[Learn More]

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

**Please a I cann't solve this problem, someone can help me?**

```
handleSubmit = event => {

event.preventDefault();
const email = document.querySelector(".email").value;
const senha = document.querySelector(".password").value;

alert(JSON.stringify({email, senha}));

const res = {
   method: 'POST',
   mode:'no-cors',
   body: JSON.stringify({email,senha}),
   headers: new Headers({
     'Content-type': 'application/json',
     'Authorization': 'Token Here',
   }),
 };
 fetch('http://rhvagas-api/login', res).then(res => res.json())
 .then(result => {
    console.log(result);
 })
}
```

**ERROR:**

[image]

**postman:**

[image]

Comment: What do you get in the alert?

Comment: Where is `JSON.parse` in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is problem with your body object.Because you are passing only value to body without key.
so body should be `body: JSON.stringify({email:email, password:senha})`